# Binary search Tree Seg faults when doing a tree walk after removing its root

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree, destructor, delete-operator

I've been stepping through my functions using pieces of paper to see what happens when I try to remove the very first Node and then print it.  Lets assume these are the elements already in the tree (depth, key, data).  WARNING/// WALL OF TEXT AHEAD!

```
1, 09/17, Paul
0, 10/24, Jen
```

I then call my remove function to remove the tree's root (Jen) and everything seems to be okay.  This is what the print function should have outputted:

```
print
0 9/17 Paul
```

However it instead segfaults and outputs:

```
print
0 p▒ p▒ ▒ ▒ ▒#a▒#a$▒#a$▒#ah▒ ... (goes on for a while)
      0 [main] BST 6176 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
354 [main] BST 6176 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to BST.exe.stackdump
```

Using GDB I type in 'where' hoping to find what line the problem occurs at in my code and I get unworldly responses:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x611298c5 in memchr () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
(gdb) where
#0  0x611298c5 in memchr () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
#1  0x779d34e3 in OutputDebugStringA ()
   from /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/KERNELBASE.dll
#2  0x40010006 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

I was hoping It would tell me why it segfaults but I have no Idea where it could be.  Ill put some source code below (note: the entire program works except for the removing part in some instances.)  I had the program sometimes just abruptly end or terminate with Aborted(core dumped).  And the tree walk always works I have inserted thousands of elements and it would always perfectly output them.  Here are the classes below: Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H_INCLUDED
#define NODE_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//class BST;
class Node
{
public:
    Node(string key, string data)
    {m_key = key; m_data = data;}
    ~Node(){
       delete m_left;
       delete m_right;
    }
    friend class BST;
private:
    string m_key;
    string m_data;
    Node *m_left;
    Node *m_right;
    Node *m_parent;
};


#endif // NODE_H_INCLUDED
```

BST.h

```
#ifndef BST_H_INCLUDED
#define BST_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Node;
class BST
{
public:
    BST()
    {m_root = NULL;}
    ~BST();
    void insert(string key, string data);

    void find(string key);
    Node* TREE_SEARCH(Node* ptr, string key);

    void remove(string key, string data);
    void TREE_DELETE(Node* ptr);
    void TRANSPLANT(Node* ptr, Node* ptr);
    Node* TREE_MINIMUM(Node* ptr);

    void print();
    void IN_ORDER_TREE_WALK(Node* ptr, int depth);
    //friend class Node;
private:
    Node* m_root;

};

#endif // BST_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is BST.cpp (note i did not include any functions that already work in my program in the post I am making.  Also to make it easier to read I will just show the destructor and all the functions that are needed to delete a node.): BST.cpp

```
#include "BST.h"
#include "Node.h"
BST::~BST()
{
    delete m_root;
    m_root = NULL;
}
Node* BST::TREE_SEARCH(Node* ptr, string key)
{
    //if(ptr != NULL)
        //cout << "SEARCHING: " <<ptr->m_key<<", " << ptr->m_data << endl;
    if(ptr == NULL || ptr->m_key == key)
        return ptr;
    if(key < ptr->m_key)
        return TREE_SEARCH(ptr->m_left, key);
    else return TREE_SEARCH(ptr->m_right, key);
}
void BST::remove(string key, string data)
{
    //cout << "preparing to remove..." << endl;
    Node* ptr = m_root;
    //if(m_root)
    Node* tmp = TREE_SEARCH(ptr, key);
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        if(tmp->m_data == data)
        {
            cout << "DELETE: " << tmp->m_key << ", " << tmp->m_data << endl << endl;
            TREE_DELETE(tmp);
            //Node* del = tmp;
            //delete del;
            delete tmp;
            return;
            //tmp = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Iterating" << endl;
            tmp = tmp->m_right; //this is the issue
        }
    }
}
void BST::TREE_DELETE(Node* z)
{
    //cout << "Changing pointers" << endl;
    if(z->m_left == NULL)
        TRANSPLANT(z, z->m_right);
    else if(z->m_right == NULL)
        TRANSPLANT(z, z->m_left);
    else
    {
        Node* y = TREE_MINIMUM(z->m_right);
        if(y->m_parent != z)
        {
            TRANSPLANT(y, y->m_right);
            y->m_right = z->m_right;
            y->m_right->m_parent = y;
        }
        TRANSPLANT(z, y);
        y->m_left = z->m_left;
        if(y->m_left != NULL)// I added this
            y->m_left->m_parent = y;
    }


}
void BST::TRANSPLANT(Node* u, Node* v)
{
    //cout << "TRANSPLANT" << endl;
    if(u->m_parent == NULL)
    {
        m_root = v;
    }
    else if(u == u->m_parent->m_left)
    {
        u->m_parent->m_left = v;
    }
    else
    {
        u->m_parent->m_right = v;
    }
    if(v != NULL)
    {
        v->m_parent = u->m_parent;
    }
}

Node* BST::TREE_MINIMUM(Node* x)
{
    //cout << "GET MIN" << endl;
    //x = m_root;
    while(x->m_left != NULL)
        x = x->m_left;
    return x;
}
```

I'll explain to the best of my ability how all of these functions work.  We start out in `int main()` where we will call `remove(key, data)` [we pass in both a key and data which will be put into a node in the tree].  Once in remove we will set a pointer to point to `m_root` and call the search function (which works perfectly, I tested it with a function that finds elements in the tree but doesn't delete them).  This function will return a pointer to the element that we want to delete.  Note: for this assignment (calendar assignment) There can be multiple things on each date (10/24) so I will have to transverse to the right until I find the data I am looking for (Jen).  Once the Node is found containing the correct data and keys I will then call `TREE_DELETE(tmp)` whose job is to get all the pointers in the other nodes in the tree pointing in the right direction.  In order to do this we will call `TRANSPLANT` (pass in 2 node pointers) to help with setting the nodes.  I have stepped through these algorithms several times and I still cannot find out why the program terminates or seg faults when I try to delete some elements.  FINAL NOTE (I got all of these algorithms out of my textbook, so they (in theory) should work perfectly.)

Comment: Where's the code that changes `m_root` if the root node is removed?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Especially check what happens on `Node`s destructor call.

Comment: When stepping through my code on a piece of paper I noticed that it would handle m_root correctly (I might be wrong though).

Comment: plus all of the code that is in ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES are from the textbook

Comment: You say that `TREE_DELETE` sets all the pointers in *other* nodes correctly, but does it also set the pointers in `tmp` to NULL? If not then `delete tmp;` is also going to delete several other nodes from your tree.

Comment: On the same line as David's question, where is the fixup of *any* node's left-or-right pointer when one of its *children* is being deleted. It would seem you're remove step never accounts for this at all. If it is in the code, I can't see it. As a side note, that `Node::Node()` doesn't default to initialize the left and right subtree pointers to `nullptr` doesn't exactly give me warm fuzzes about the quality of your book.

Comment: John, you were correct (it gets hard think and code when you are programming all day)  I set all of tmps pointers to null and then deleted it and now it works perfectly! (still gotta test it some more) But thankyou for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the print function would seg fault was because when i called delete on that certain pointer it would delete EVERYTHING underneath it.  my solution was: [thanks again john]

```
void BST::remove(string key, string data)
{
    Node* ptr = m_root;
    Node* tmp = TREE_SEARCH(ptr, key);
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        if(tmp->m_data == data)
        {
            TREE_DELETE(tmp);
            tmp->m_parent = NULL;
            tmp->m_right = NULL;
            tmp->m_left = NULL;
            delete tmp;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = tmp->m_right;
        }
    }
}
```